# Wrong title for documents library : "Documents ressources[3]"

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I'm sorry if I translate it wrong but, as the title says, I have a "[3]" just after my documents ressources. This is a webpart from my Sharepoint site.

It's probably because I have "ghost" libraries but impossible to find them!

Here's a screenshot to show you what I'm talking about :

[image: See it in the title]

If you have an idea, don't hesitate. I already did search with our dear friend Google but I have difficulties to use the correct terms.

Have a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That notation usually means that there are multiple web parts with the same name on the same page. (Not multiple libraries, multiple web parts.)

If your URL contains a question mark (?) add this to the end: &Contents=1
If it does not contain a question mark then add this: ?Contents=1

This will redirect to _layouts/15/spcontnt.aspx and list all of the web parts on the page.